# Not possible to publish artifact to shared location in TFS

Tags: tfs

[image: Tfs Build]I tried to publish artifact to shared location. I have shown in picture my build definition. In the shared location, I have given read/ write permission to everyone.

But still I am getting this error while publishing artifact:

> [error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Unable to
>   create directory '{p}'. Unable to verify the directory exists:
>   '{testDir}'. If directory is a file share, please verify the share
>   name is correct, the share is online, and the current process has
>   permission to access the share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not possible to publish artifact to shared location in TFS

To use the shared location for TFS, you should make sure the name of your host which is available on the **network**.

Basically, this is what the error message is about:

> If directory is a file share, please verify the share name is correct,
>   the share is online, and the current process has permission to access
>   the share.

So, we'd better open that shared folder on the machine that is running the build pipeline to check if it can be accessed.

For example:

I created a shared folder on the TFS server machine, given `read/write` permission to everyone. The Network path is `\\WS-TFS2017-5044\LeoTestShareFolder`.

[image]

**Then** on the machine which I execute the build pipeline, I open the file system and type the above Network path:

[image]

As you can see, I could access that shared folder from network, in this case, we could add the Network path `\\WS-TFS2017-5044\LeoTestShareFolder` to the Publish Build Artifacts task.

As test, I could publish artifact to shared location in TFS (The `drop` folder in above image.).

Hope this helps.